# Generar una lista a partir de las keys de un diccionario tomando en cuenta los valores de estas keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, estructuras-de-datos, diccionarios

Por ejemplo si se tiene el siguiente diccionario:

```
{1:2, 2:3}
```

quiero obtener la siguiente lista:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Es decir: hay tantos "1" como valores indica el valor de la clave "1" (2) y tantos "2" como valores indica el valor de la clave "2" (3).

Comment: Hola Felka98, ¿Lo has intentado simplemente con dos `for`?, uno recorriendo el diccionario y otro con `range(valor)`.

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo de lo que dices?

Answer (score 2):

Una forma podría ser la siguiente:

```
d = {1:2,2:3}

l=[]
map(l.extend, ([k]*d[k] for k in d))
print(l)

[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

`([k]*d[k] for k in d)` es una expresión generadora que genera un conjunto 
de listas, cada una tiene el valor de cada clave del diccionario repetido por el valor de dicha clave, es decir: `[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]`. Transformar esto en una lista plana es tan simple como aplicar a cada sublista el `extend` de una lista vacía.

Answer (score 0):

Es una pregunta vieja, pero creo que aporto al dar esta solución, que es distinta a la de **Patricio Moracho**, pero igual de efectiva:

```
dc = {1:2, 2:3}
lst = sum([[x]*y for x, y in dc.items()], [])

print(lst)

[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Por un lado estoy haciendo *list comprehension* para crear una lista de listas al estilo `[[1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]` y luego las concateno con `sum`.